My collider is not detecting collision. Unity2D
It does not detect collision. (I have been trying to fix this for 3 days now)
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [Header("Ectoplasm Reward")]
     public int ectoplasmReward = 10; // Amount of ectoplasm to reward when killed
 
     [Header("Respawn Settings")]
     public float respawnTime = 5f; // Time to respawn in seconds
     private bool isDead = false;
 
     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collisionInfo) // This collision does not detect
     {
         if (collisionInfo.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "HurtBox")
         {
             isDead = true;
             // Add ectoplasm reward
             StatManager.instance.AddEctoplasm(ectoplasmReward);
             // Disable enemy
             gameObject.SetActive(false);
             // Start respawn timer
             Invoke("RespawnEnemy", respawnTime);
         }
         else // Even this does not run
         {
             Debug.Log("Collision Detected, Wrong Tag");
         }
     }
 
     private void RespawnEnemy()
     {
         // Enable enemy
         gameObject.SetActive(true);
         isDead = false;
     }
 }

I think it might have to do with the script that makes my sword swing. It disables the sword at first. then re-enables it for the swings and disables it again..
using UnityEngine;

public class SwordSwing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pivotObject; // Reference to the pivot object
    public GameObject sword; // Reference to the sword object
    public float swingSpeed = 360f; // degrees per second
    public float swingAngle = 180f; // total swing angle
    public float cooldownTime = 2f; // cooldown time in seconds

    private bool isSwinging = false;
    private bool isCooldown = false;
    private float currentAngle = 0f;
    private float cooldownTimer = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        sword.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isCooldown)
        {
            cooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (cooldownTimer >= cooldownTime)
            {
                isCooldown = false;
                cooldownTimer = 0f;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !isSwinging && !isCooldown)
        {
            isSwinging = true;
            sword.SetActive(true); // Enable the sword
        }

        if (isSwinging)
        {
            SwingSword();
        }
    }

    void SwingSword()
    {
        float angleThisFrame = swingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        pivotObject.Rotate(0, 0, angleThisFrame);
        currentAngle += angleThisFrame;

        if (currentAngle >= swingAngle)
        {
            isSwinging = false;
            currentAngle = 0f;
            pivotObject.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); // Reset rotation if necessary
            sword.SetActive(false); // Disable the sword
            isCooldown = true; // Start the cooldown
        }
    }
}

But the sword and enemy both have box colliders and rigidbodys set up (Rigidbody has simulator off because the game is top-down-view)
Here are some screenshots:
Player Screenshots
The player object with the SwordSwing script attached

Sword Screenshots


Enemy Screenshots
The Enemy Script Attached to the enemy

Enemy Rigidbody And BoxCollider

I tried using OnCollisionEnter And OnTriggerEnter but it still wont detect it. What im trying to do is when the player swings their sword at the enemy their Ectoplasm goes up and the enemy gets disabled for respawnTime amount of seconds.

You disabled both Rigidbody2D via Simulated

When not simulated, any attached Collider2D or Joint2D also do not participate in the physics simulation.

If anything you probably rather wanted to set them to be kinematic instead
